# In /proc/sockstat which TCP states count as 'inuse' and which count as 'alloc'?

Tags: linux, networking, tcp, kernel

For example, in /proc/net/sockstat , does a TCP socket in CLOSE_WAIT get counted as 'inuse' or 'alloc' ?

In the kernel source net/ipv4/proc.c I see that  [sockstat_seq_show](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.8/source/net/ipv4/proc.c#L52) is called when getting the info from /proc/net/sockstat.

However I cannot see what differentiates a socket from being allocated (alloc) opposed to 'inuse'

```
[me@myhostname ~]$ cat /proc/net/sockstat
sockets: used 481
TCP: inuse 52 orphan 1 tw 66 alloc 62 mem 12
UDP: inuse 11 mem 5
UDPLITE: inuse 0
RAW: inuse 0
FRAG: inuse 0 memory 0
```

In net/tcp_states.h the possible states are enumerated as such

```
enum {
    TCP_ESTABLISHED = 1,
    TCP_SYN_SENT,
    TCP_SYN_RECV,
    TCP_FIN_WAIT1,
    TCP_FIN_WAIT2,
    TCP_TIME_WAIT,
    TCP_CLOSE,
    TCP_CLOSE_WAIT,
    TCP_LAST_ACK,
    TCP_LISTEN,
    TCP_CLOSING,    /* Now a valid state */
    TCP_NEW_SYN_RECV,

    TCP_MAX_STATES  /* Leave at the end! */
```

};

Which of the above count as 'inuse' and which count as 'alloc' ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Which of the above count as 'inuse' and which count as 'alloc' ?

You already got close to the answer by locating `sockstat_seq_show` - we can see that 'inuse' is the value of [`sock_prot_inuse_get(net, &tcp_prot)`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.8/ident/sock_prot_inuse_get), and 'alloc' is the value of [`proto_sockets_allocated_sum_positive(&tcp_prot)`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.8/ident/proto_sockets_allocated_sum_positive). Now it's not always easy to follow the call chain further down, but I, if not mistaken, arrive at the following conclusions.

1. 'alloc' - This at bottom is the sum of [`percpu_counter tcp_sockets_allocated`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.8/ident/tcp_sockets_allocated), which gets incremented in [`tcp_init_sock()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.8/source/net/ipv4/tcp.c#L426); there the socket state is initialized to `TCP_CLOSE`. Whatever state changes the socket undergoes during its existence, 'alloc' doesn't depend on - all TCP states *count as 'alloc'*.
2. 'inuse' - This is the sum of the (per CPU) counters `net->core.inuse` or `prot_inuse` (for the TCP in this case), which essentially get incremented and decremented by calls of `sock_prot_inuse_add(…, 1)` resp. `(…, -1)` in [`inet_hash()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.8/ident/inet_hash) resp. [`inet_unhash()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.8/ident/inet_unhash). The condition in `inet_hash()` is `if (sk->sk_state != TCP_CLOSE)`, so all TCP states except `TCP_CLOSE` *count as 'inuse'*.

> I think this means in theory any socket in a state >= TCP_CLOSE is not counted as 'inuse'

In my view that can't be so, since also TCP_LISTEN > TCP_CLOSE, and a socket in TCP_LISTEN state surely is *counted as 'inuse'*, as can be seen with e. g.

```
(cd /proc/net; cat sockstat; nc -l 8888& sleep 1; cat sockstat; kill $!; cat sockstat)|grep TCP
```

Comment: I think that just means sockets where sk->sk_state != TCP_CLOSE can increment the counter. inet_unhash() can still get called and decrement that counter. When we call inet_hash() and inet_unhash() functions we are working with the kernel's net connection hash table, which defines the following invariant (recall the enum of possible states)
  TCP_ESTABLISHED <= sk->sk_state < TCP_CLOSE
which i believe means that inet_unhash() will be called when sk->sk_state > TCP_CLOSE which TCP_CLOSE_WAIT is. I think this means in theory any socket in  a state >= TCP_CLOSE is not counted as 'inuse'

Comment: Where did you derive the invariant from? - I expanded my answer.

Comment: You are correct, I tested on a server and sockets in CLOSE_WAIT are definitely counted as 'inuse' in sockstat. The invariant comes from the comments in inet_hashtables.h  
 https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.8/source/include/net/inet_hashtables.h#L116

Comment: Very clear explanation, however from there I don't understand why we can see that  tw > alloc here ?

Comment: I'm sorry - I've never seen this and have no explanation.

Comment: @Armali ok, thank you for having a look !